# Format for a description html and css

Tags: html, css

I want my description to be like this I can do it with margin, float and width but if I do that and make the resolution resize it will be a messed up layout.
so what other method do you think I need to use?

```
[IMG1 | description text  | [IMG2
 IMG1 | description text  |  IMG2
 IMG1 |  text text text   |  IMG2
IMG1] |     text text     |  IMG2]
```

### HTML

```
<div class="headbapt">
    <img class="bapt" src="images/baptismal.jpg">Sacrament of Baptism is the first step in a lifelong journey of commitment and discipleship. Whether we are baptized as infants or adults, Baptism is the Church's way of celebrating and enacting the embrace of God.
    <img class="bapt2" src="images/baptismal.jpg">
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.headbapt {
     text-align:center;
}
.baptdesc {
    width: 295px;
    margin-left: 40%;
}
.bapt {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 35%;
}
.bapt2 {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 32.5%;
    margin-top: -8.5%;
}
```

Comment: can you post a fiddle of whatever you have till now

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/H4u4e/
there if i have small resolution its messed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use tables? They are in HTML for a purpose and that's (or at last seems to be) exactly the case you should use them!

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><img class="bapt" src="images/baptismal.jpg"></td>
        <td>Sacrament of Baptism is the first step in a lifelong journey of commitment and discipleship. Whether we are baptized as infants or adults, Baptism is the Church's way of celebrating and enacting the embrace of God.</td>
        <td><img class="bapt2" src="images/baptismal.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- and so on... -->
</table>
```

Nothing more needed.

Comment: never thought of that i have different pov for tables. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Why done u use 3 divs . First and last div give float left and right and middle div float:left

```
        <div class="descr">
            <div class="leftimg">
                <img class="bapt2" src="images/baptismal.jpg">
             </div>
             <div class="text">

              </div>
             <div class="rightimg">
                <img class="bapt2" src="images/baptismal.jpg">
              </div>
        </div>
```